# Как применить двойную сортировку?

Tags: php, битрикс

Имею проблему с сортировкой в таблице. Есть стандартное строение листа(таблицы):

```
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array("PROPERTY_P_DATE" => "DESC"), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);
```

Но к сожалению нужно сделать сортировку не только по `PROPERTY_P_DATE`, но и по `DATE_ACTIVE_FROM`. Попробовал сделать такую конструкцию:

```
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(
       "LOGIC" => "AND",
       array("PROPERTY_P_DATE" => "DESC"),
       array("DATE_ACTIVE_FROM" => "ASC")), 
       $arFilter, 
       false, 
       false, 
       $arSelect);
```

К сожалению не сработало, сортировка вообще не отрабатывала, вернее в одностороннем порядке. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно установить сортировку больше чем по одному элементу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что мешает в одном массиве перечислить несколько сортировок:

```
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(array(
         array("PROPERTY_P_DATE" => "DESC", "DATE_ACTIVE_FROM" => "ASC"),
         $arFilter, 
         false, 
         false, 
         $arSelect
       );
```

Comment: Пробовал... Вылет в ошибку и только - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected

Comment: Тьфу... простите дурака... запятую забыл убрать... Отработало =)

Comment: @ДмитрийГончаров, так может в синтаксисе была ошибка а не в этом коде?)

Comment: а ну вот) будем засчитывать ответ или как?

Comment: Кинул бы лайкос сразу, но ток через 7 минут =)